# Make a module out of the mobilize

Tags: 7

I tried using [mobilize](http://mobilizejs.com/) and made my drupal site mobile ready very fast i.e. added the java script code directly in the theme `page.tpl.php` file. I wanted to make this a module and made a new module and added code like below and enabled the module, But mobile version of website doesn't work. Any thing wrong i ma doing? mobilize is the module name

```
<?php
function mobilize_init() {
 $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mobilize'); 
 drupal_add_js($path . '/site.js', 'file');
drupal_add_js('http://cdn.mobilizejs.com/releases/0.1/js/mobilize.core.min.js','external');
}
?>
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What's in the site.js file? Do you see the scripts output on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hook seems to be named as if it was a mobilize one, where it should be named by your module's. something like "my_module_init".